# Defer message - "The Rebus transport message ID can not be overwritten"

Tags: rebus

I am having some trouble with Rebus and defer messages, something like this:

```
    bus.AttachHeader(message, "attempt_no", deliveryAttempt + 1);
    bus.Defer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), message);
```

At least some times I am logging errors like this, that I can't explain, and do I have to be concerned about this issue?

**StackTrace**

```
System.ArgumentException: The Rebus transport message ID can not be overwritten.
   at Rebus.Bus.RebusBus.AttachHeader(Object message, String key, String value)
   at Rebus.Bus.DeferredMessageReDispatcher.DispatchLocal(Object deferredMessage, Guid sagaId, IDictionary`2 headers)
   at Rebus.Bus.TimeoutReplyHandler.Handle(TimeoutReply message)
   at Rebus.Bus.Dispatcher.<DoDispatch>d__24`1.MoveNext()
```

Update:

My setup is that I have a Publish/Subscriber and if the subscriber fails I want it to retry a number of times in a matter that is logic to its purpose.

So at subscriber I set this up like this, I guess this is the originator of these exceptions:

```
        var bus = Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
                           .Logging(l => l.NLog())
                           .Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
                           .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
                           .Timeouts(t => t. StoreInSqlServer(connection.ConnectionString, "Rebus.TimeoutTable").EnsureTableIsCreated())
                           .CreateBus().Start();
```

So I believe that that means it is using the Internal Timeout manager and stores this in my SQL Server, this works as assumed in most cases, still I get the above exceptions from time to time.

Comment: can you please attach small reproductive sample?

Comment: could you maybe elaborate i little bit on your setup? (internal/external timeout manager?, which transport?)

Comment: excellent, thanks - I'll see if I can reproduce it